# azure sql server v12 show incorrect metric

Tags: azure-sql-database

I found the in MS Azure SQL Server v12 performance metric is show different value between "past hour" and "today".

Sorry i can't post the image due to my reputation is not enough..
If i see at "past hour" metric, i'll see almost 100% utilization of CPU and DTU but if i see at "today" metric, i'll see only 18% DTU and 53% CPU. Not sure which one is correct?

And I also can't see connection metric, It's always show "No available data"

Last Sat (Feb-28), MS Azure notice user that they found issue on historical metric, not sure is they completely solve the issue or not?, I try to ask their support, they always said this's preview version and not in scope of their support. :(

Is anyone got the same issue?

My sql db is P3, size around 13GB only.

Answer (score 1):

The telemetry for the past hour is always the most price data. If you look over longer periods of time you will see an average consumption over the interval that will hide peaks in your utilization unless the utilization is constant.

You can also query the 1 hour data directly in the database by querying the view sys.dm_db_resouce_stats It will show the data in 15s intervals.

Jan